# Firebase migration between projects - Destination Fire Store database doesn't change on Import command (No Error Displayed)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-datastore

The import command from the bucket doesn't affect the Firestore database. I have been trying to migrate the data from one project to another. Both of the projects are in blaze plan and are in the same google account. Both the buckets are there on the google cloud console for each project. There was no error shown in the cloud shell. The following message was shown at the end of import command.

```
    metadata:
   '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.firestore.admin.v1.ImportDocumentsMetadata
    inputUriPrefix: gs://rit_test_migration_bucket_pk_dep/2021-05-21T10:13:32_45764
    operationState: PROCESSING
    startTime: '2021-05-21T10:20:15.394043Z'
    name: projects/project-tiedge- 
  test/databases/(default)/operations/AiAyNzc1NzEzMzYJGnRsdWFmZWQHEmVwb3J1ZS1zYm9qLW5pbWRhEQopEg
```

Source Bucket Name: rit_test_migration_bucket_pk_dev

Destination Bucket Name: rit_test_migration_bucket_pk_dep

Following Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data

Steps Done:

1. Created a bucket in the source project through google cloud console, exported the data of that database to that bucket with the help of the following command in the cloud shell

   ```
    gcloud firestore export gs://rit_test_migration_bucket_pk_dev --async
   ```
2. Transferred the bucket to another project bucket through the help of transfer page at google cloud console

   Ref Link: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets
3. Trying to import the data of that database to that bucket with the help of the following command in the cloud shell

   ```
    gcloud firestore import gs://rit_test_migration_bucket_pk_dev/2019-03-05T20:58:23_56418 --async
   ```

Comment: Just curious, but what state is the new project's firestore? is it in datastore mode?

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore

Comment: @DIGIByte How can I check for that, I have no idea about it? I think I have found the issue, my one database storage region is Asia while the other one is Europe. Maybe because of this it was not importing as the bucket was also in European region.

Answer (score 0):

The bucket doesn't imply the project in the gcloud command line.  You'll want to be explicit with each command.  E.g. `gcloud --project=source_project export gs://...`, then `gcloud --project=destination_project import gs://same-path-should-work`.

Comment: I have already selected the projects with the help of this command `gcloud config set project [SOURCE_PROJECT_ID]` before import-export.

Comment: The output from the import command shows the long running operation metadata.  You can check any LROs with `gcloud firestore operations list` (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/operations/list)